# Inserting alternate timestamp formats to Hive

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, timestamp, hive-serde

So I am trying to upload a csv file through Hive but the csv file has timestamps as one of the formats, the timestamps are of the format dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS. I added this in the SerdeProperties but the Serde I am using is OpenCSVSerde which parses everything to a string so my data is no longer a timestamp. Is there another SerDe I can use?

```
    CREATE TABLE `w_sna.data_schema10`(
  `dataschema_name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `last_updated` timestamp COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `dataschema_def` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'separatorChar'=',', 
  'timestamp.formats'='dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS')
```

Comment: did you take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502021/hive-date-timestamp-column/52502379#52502379?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it isn't working, elaborating on this: if I don't specify a serde in Hive it defaults to LazySimpleSerde which then for some reason will collapse all the data into one column even if there is a separator character specified in the SerDeProperties

Comment: Your `dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS `needs to be `dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS.`. Year is  **yyyy**, not **YYYY**.

Comment: That seems to have helped, thank you